# с++: ожидание события некоторыми потоками

Tags: c++, многопоточность, stl

подскажите как реализовать функциями из stl следующую задачу:

у меня потокам раздаются последовательно задачи (задачу упростил чтобы много кода не писать):

```
void mythread::thread_func(...)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // получить задачу
        m_lock.lock();

        const int index = m_global_index;
        m_global_index ++;

        m_lock.unlock();

        // выполнить задачу    
}
```

ТОЛЬКО (!!!) когда все задачи выполнены начинают выдаваться следующие задачи

возможна ситуация, когда один поток еще выполняет последнюю задачу, а новый поток уже хочет получить следующую, но пока задач нет ему надо подождать

**подскажите как это корректно реализовать?**

т.е. должно быть что-то на подобии:

```
void mythread::thread_func(...)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // получить задачу
        m_lock.lock();

        // если старых задач уже не осталось, но они еще не выполнены всеми потоками - подождать
        if (m_global_index > m_max_index)
            std::wait(....); // какая-то функция, позволяющая подождать события
                
        const int index = m_global_index;
        m_global_index ++;

        m_lock.unlock();

        // выполнить задачу    

        // если это была последняя задача - сгенерировать событие для запуска с ожидания остальных потоков
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable думаю это то что вам нужно

Comment: Новую задачу получит тот кто первым заблокирует мьютекс.

Comment: @mik.ov, по идее первую из новых задач получит (должен получить) тот, кто сделает последнюю из старых задач, а дальше задачи должны начать получать остальные потоки

Comment: Заведите 2 переменные, для блокировки ожидания поступления новой задачи, и сигнал на начало выполнения последней задачи, тем самым заблокирует все потоки которые хотят новых задач до тех пор пока последний не выполнит действие, а далее дайте сигнал на поступление новых данных, и так по кругу. Только не забудьте дать сигнал на то что началось выполнение задачи, и ее окончании если она последняя, так потоки смогут ожидать окончания всех работ, а вы им тем временем подсуньте новые задачи, и дайте сигнал на выполнение.

Comment: Чуть не забыл, что бы не получить дед лок, не позволяйте последнему кто начал выполнять задачу освобождать мьютекс, т.е. прямо перед разблокировкой проверьте состояние на новые данные, и только потом отпустите его. Т.е. именно там ждите новых задач. Не обязательно последний должен начать работу первым.

Comment: @mik.ov, так вот мне и интересно как это сделать, в WinAPI я бы просто сделал `SetEvent/ResetEvent` и `::WaitForSingleObject`, а вот как в stl это реализовать (ну или аналог)

Comment: Я бы написал пример, но увы около компьютера буду только завтра вечером.